# Problem with SQL Express aliases under Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, sql-server-express

Recently upgraded to Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit and Visual Studio 2010.  In previous versions, we set up an alias to SQL Express 2008 to use localhost instead of .\SQLEXPRESS, so that our config files don't need to change when checking into TFS before being deployed to staging or wherever.  After the upgrade, I can connect to SQL Express 2008 using SSMS and the localhost alias, but Visual Studio 2010 and IIS don't seem to be aware of it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

On 64-bit systems, when you run cliconfg.exe to create an alias, it by default runs the 64-bit version found at C:\Windows\System32 and puts the alias info into the registry at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo
```

However, Visual Studio is a 32-bit application so it can't 'see' the alias definition that was added to the registry in the (64-bit) default path.

The solution is to create a 32-bit version of the alias, either by running the 32-bit version of cliconfg at C:\Windows\SysWOW64 or by adding the alias to the 32-bit equivalent location in the registry at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo
```